# How to remove a multi method in Raku

Tags: raku, nqp

How can I augment a class with a multi-method that will be called before the already defined one ?

I am trying to enable negative subscript: `@arr[-1]` like in [this](https://andrewshitov.com/2018/01/07/18-implementing-negative-array-subscripts-in-perl-6/) article but without changing the source.

So I augment [Array](https://docs.raku.org/type/Array) with:

```
augment class Array { 
    proto method AT-POS(Array:D: Int:D $i where <0 ) {
        say "AT-POS called";
        my $pos = -1;
        my $ix = $pos + self.elems;
        return self.AT-POS($ix);
    }
};
```

But as stated in the [doc](https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#Augmenting_a_class)

```
Please note that adding a multi candidate that differs only
in its named parameters will add that candidate behind the already defined one
and as such it won't be picked by the dispatcher.
```

So my multi is never called:

```
say .signature for @arr.^method_table{'AT-POS'}.candidates ;
```

```
(Any:U \SELF: int \pos, *%_)
(Any:U \SELF: Int:D \pos, *%_)
(Any:U: Num:D \pos, *%_)
(Any:U: Any:D \pos, *%_)
(Any:D: int \pos, *%_)
(Any:D: Int:D \pos, *%_)
(Any:D: Num:D \pos, *%_)
(Any:D: Any:D \pos, *%_)
($: Any:U \pos, *%_)
(Any:D: \one, \two, *%_)
(Any:D: \one, \two, \three, *%_)
(Any:D: **@indices, *%_)
(List:D: int $pos, *%_)
(List:D: Int:D $pos, *%_)
(Array:D: int $pos, *%_)
(Array:D: Int:D $pos, *%_)  # Their
(Array: $a, *%_)
(Array:D: Int:D $pos, *%_)  # My
```

I want my method to be called before their. How can can I modify the dispatcher?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Named parameters don't come into the matter; there aren't any here. The problem is that instead of adding a `multi` candidate that is more specific, the code in the question instead tries to replace the `proto`. If instead a `multi` candidate is added like this:

```
use MONKEY-TYPING;
augment class Array { 
    multi method AT-POS(Array:D: Int:D $i where $i < 0) {
        nextwith($i + self.elems)
    }
}
```

Then, due to the presence of the `where` clause, it will be considered before the usual `AT-POS` candidate without one. Since the standard candidate still applies too, `nextwith` can be used to defer to it. Using the above `augment`, the program:

```
my @arr = 1, 2, 3;
my $idx = -1;
say @arr[$idx];
```

Will output `3`.

The usual caveats about `augment` apply, and since every array index operation will pay this cost, expect a significant slowdown.

Comment: I copied badly, it was actually `multi` (made many tries). Copying your code in the same file works. But if I `augment` in an included module, the new multi (`(Array:D: Int:D $i where { ... }, *%_)`) appears but is not called. Do you know why ?

Comment: .... But if I augment a useless `AT-POS` also in the current file, then the imported multi can be called. It seems that some composition some runtime is missing.

Comment: Try adding `no precompilation` in the module that does the `augment`.

Comment: `no precompilation`. Well this works ! I wouldn't have find it => Thanks for your awesome answers. You may not see from your side of the cable it but it helps a LOT in this side.